# Trombone sheet music help

Tags: sheet-music

I don't know how to play the notes that are stacked on each other and and what they mean but the 12 over 8 thing[image: this is the image]

Comment: If 2 notes are stacked on top of each other, that means that 1 trombonist plays the high notes and the other play the low notes. And 12/8 is basically 4/4 in triplets. In other words, every eighth note in 12/8 is equal to 1 note of an eighth note triplet in 4/4. So if you count it like this 1 & a 2 & a 3 & a 4 & a, that is valid for either 4/4 with triplets or 12/8

Comment: Also note that your score says "Trombone 1 & 2", which means that it contains the parts of more than 1 trombone player.

Comment: @Caters: This should have been an answer.

Comment: Related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/61682/2600) and instructive answer.

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to answer when I found this in the reviews. That's why I commented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this note have a stem pointing up and another pointing down?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/why-does-this-note-have-a-stem-pointing-up-and-another-pointing-down)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - hardly, as in this example they all point the same way! So, not dupe. But it does explain what *should* have been written!

Answer (score 6):

Hoping someone else may have answered by now! There are two notes stacked all the way through this sheet music. It would be better to understand if the top note of each pair had an upward stem, and the bottom a downward stem. Not possible with notes like a semibreve!

As there are two notes, it makes it so that each trombonist has his own line to play. Tr.1 plays top notes, tr.2 bottom. hard to get mixed up usually, and on the occasions where both play unison, that's where the stems issue makes things clearer.

12/8? Well, it means there are 12 'little' beats of a quaver (eighth note) are in each bar (measure) - or their equivalent. Usually gets counted **1** 2 3 **4** 5 6 **7** 8 9 **10** 11 12. So, a kind of 4 count, with each count split in to 3.